# Can i upgrade the .Net Framework 3.5 to 4 when i have a running Sharepoint(Windows SharePoint Services 3).Whats the impact?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, upgrade

We are thinking of upgrading the  .Net Framework  3.5 to 4 while an existing Windows SharePoint Services v3 is running.
Is this safe or it will break the installation.
Would there b3 any impact on the sharepoint instance?

Cheers

Comment: Isn't this the point of dev/test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net 3.5 and 4 have different CLR versions and can be installed side by side on the same machines, so you can install .Net 4 on your SharePoint servers with no problem.

But code written for .Net 3.5 can't run on the new CLR without a recompile, so you can't swithch your SharePoint application pools to run .Net 4, but you may have other web sites, services, utilities, ... running .Net 4 on the machine. These will not be able to use the SharePoint object model though.

The upcomming SharePoint 2013 is running .Net 4.5

Comment: Thanks Per.I know i could run it side by side.
But was't sure of any other impact on the sharepoint instance.